# C++ Programming with textFiles

Tags: c++, text-files, return-type

I am currently working on a program which stores a string in a Text File.
As you would see at the code i entered a return statement at the end of my if Conditional. But when i execute it the second time the text file has not recorded any of the data i wanted to store and print next, it just shows blank space.Does it work this way? What am i doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,d;
    ofstream k("t1.txt");
    int a;

    cout<<"Vendosni nje numer 1/2 ";
    cin>>a;

    if(a==1){
        while(k.is_open()){
            cin.ignore();
            cout<<"Vendosni nje pyetje: ";
            getline(cin,s);
            cout<<"Vendosni alternativen 1: ";
            getline(cin,s1);
            cout<<"Vendosni alternativen 2: ";
            getline(cin,s2);
            cout<<"Vendosni alternativen 3: ";
            getline(cin,s3);
            cout<<"Vendosni alternativen 4: ";
            getline(cin,s4);
            cout<<"Vendosni pergjigjen: ";
            getline(cin,s5);


            k<<s<<endl;
            k<<s1<<endl;
            k<<s2<<endl;
            k<<s3<<endl;
            k<<s4<<endl;

            k.close();

            return main();
        }
    } else {
        ifstream r("t1.txt");
        while( r.is_open() ) {
            for( int i=0; i<5; i++ ) {
                getline(r, d);
                cout<<d<<endl;
            }

            r.close();
        }
        string s6;
        cin>>s6;

        if(s6==s5){
            cout<<"True";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For me the return main() have no sense, it will open again the file in write mode and it will overwrite the t1 file. Also it never will get the second part of the code (except if opening file for write fails). So I recomend to rewrite the code. Making main recursive dont looks a clar code.

Comment: @Mquinteiro how should i write the code so i can load what i store if add a return main statement?

Comment: I acctually can't understand what are you traying to do. You start writing into a file some information that you catch from console. But what do you want to do after that? If you check you are returning from main with nothing or with the result of main() (that at the end only can be nothing)

Comment: @Mquinteiro Im writing a question with different alternatives and a answer....and id like to return to main so that i can take the question and give it an answer

Answer (score -1):

When you are opening a file you have to define mode of the file - read mode or write mode or both. below given the edited code with file mode

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string s,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,d;
        ofstream k("t1.txt", ofstream::app);
        int a;
        cout<<"Vendosni nje numer 1/2 ";
        cin>>a;
        if(a==1)
        {

            while(k.is_open())
            {
                cin.ignore();
                cout<<"Vendosni nje pyetje: ";
                getline(cin,s);
                cout<<"Vendosni alternativen 1: ";
                getline(cin,s1);
                cout<<"Vendosni alternativen 2: ";
                getline(cin,s2);
                cout<<"Vendosni alternativen 3: ";
                getline(cin,s3);
                cout<<"Vendosni alternativen 4: ";
                getline(cin,s4);
                cout<<"Vendosni pergjigjen: ";
                getline(cin,s5);


                k<<s<<endl;
                k<<s1<<endl;
                k<<s2<<endl;
                k<<s3<<endl;
                k<<s4<<endl;
                k<<s5<<endl;
                k.close();
                return main();


            }
        }
        else
        {

            ifstream r("t1.txt",ofstream::in);
            while(r.is_open())
            {
                for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
                {
                    getline(r,d);
                    cout<<d<<endl;
                }
                getline(r,d);
                r.close();

            }
            string s6;
            cin>>s6;


            if(s6==d)
            {
                cout<<"True";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didnt understand

Comment: when you open a file you need to specify for which purpose you will open the file - read data from the file of write data in the file, or for both purpose. these specification called mode of the file: 
three file mode is - 
in - write mode
out- read mode
app - both read and write

for example:  ofstream k("t1.txt", ofstream::app);

Comment: i have corrected your code adding these command in my ans see the file opening statement.

Comment: if i try to load the data and give the right answer it doesnt print anything...i expect to print true

Comment: when reading the data, you saved id to variable d and your are trying to match s6 with s5 instead of d
so use if(s6==d) instead of if(s6==s5)

Comment: it still doesnt print it

Comment: you haven't save the ans in the file. that's why it is not showing. i have edited code in the ans. try that